# OpenVPN bridge gateway stops all traffic

Tags: linux, openvpn, bridge, gateway

I am not sure if this is a linux or windows issue. I have openvpn set up with a bridge interface that includes tap0 and eth0. I have my client machine (win10) getting its IP through my dhcp server. The config line `server-bridge` causes the dhcp gateway to be stripped out so the client doesn't receive it. When I change that line to `server-bridge nogw` the gateway address is given to the client, but I can't ping or connect to the gateway. What do I have wrong?

Client (win10) routing table

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1     192.168.1.79     10
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
       172.16.0.0      255.255.0.0         On-link      172.16.1.205    257
     172.16.1.205  255.255.255.255         On-link      172.16.1.205    257
   172.16.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      172.16.1.205    257
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.1.79    266
     192.168.1.79  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.79    266
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.79    266
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.1.79    266
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      172.16.1.205    257
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.79    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      172.16.1.205    257
===========================================================================
```

When I have it working correctly, routing traffic through the VPN, the following lines are added to the routing table:

```
0.0.0.0     0.0.0.0       172.16.0.1  172.16.1.205 2
64.191.11.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.96 61
```

The second line allows the VPN traffic to use the original gateway.

OpenVPN Server conf file

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tap
ca /etc/openvpn/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/myservername.crt
key /etc/openvpn/myservername.key  # This file should be kept secret
dh /etc/openvpn/dh2048.pem
server-bridge
script-security 2
up "up br0 eth0"
down "down br0 eth0"
down-pre
push "dhcp-option DNS 172.16.0.1"
client-to-client
keepalive 10 120
tls-auth /etc/openvpn/ta.key 0 # This file is secret
cipher BF-CBC        # Blowfish (default)
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
```

Adding `nogw` to the `server-bridge` line allows the gateway to go through on dhcp but I can't reach the server anymore. the scripts `up` and `down` add the tap interface to the bridge or remove it.

OpenVPN client conf:

```
client
dev tap
remote jmerrill.us 1194
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\ca.crt"
cert "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\client1.crt"
key "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\client1.key"
tls-auth "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\ta.key" 1
cipher BF-CBC
comp-lzo
verb 3
```

Comment: What does your routing table say?

Comment: @roaima my thought was that the client isn't on the same network as the gateway. But that's a pretty specific guess on my part and you are right to just ask for the config

Comment: @user1794469 The client vpn connection is on the same network as the server's LAN because of the bridge.

Comment: @roaima I have added more info. Do you need anything else?

Comment: @user1794469 I did figure out something. The reason it is cutting off communication is because the vpn traffic was trying to follow the route as well. When I set a route for the vpn server address to follow the normal gateway, I can use a gateway address without any trouble. Unfortunately, that means that I have to manually add the routes every time.

Comment: @user1794469 Here are the lines I added to the routing table that worked correctly:
      0.0.0.0            0.0.0.0                  172.16.0.1       172.16.1.205      2
      64.191.11.0    255.255.255.0      192.168.1.1     192.168.1.96     61

Comment: You shouldn't have to add the routes manually every time. You can make them part of the interface config and they will get added when the interface comes up.

Comment: When I allow dhcp to set the gateway, the traffic that maintains the vpn gets routed as well and it looks for the remote gateway in the local network. I have to set a route to the vpn server to fix that.

Comment: do you mean you don't know the address you need to add until the dhcp goes through? Or you always want to add the same routes? Either way we can set this up so it happens with a script, you won't have to do it manually every time.

Comment: I know the address I need to change the route for. But depending on where I connect from, the gateway may be different.

Comment: James this is fairly easy to fix. Please add your updates such as the routing table and clarifications of the problem back into your question (so the content can be formatted properly). You can then delete your comments as they're no longer required. And I'll try to get you an answer tomorrow (Friday).

Comment: I've read through the comments again. I don't see what's missing from the post.